# Can't join homegroup, both computers say the other computer knows the password

Tags: windows-10, homegroup

I have three computers on my network - let's call them Alice, Bob and Charlie.  Alice is my girlfriend's computer, Bob is my laptop, and Charlie is the newcomer - my desktop PC.

When I tried to add Charlie to the homegroup, I was told that Alice knew the password - so I interrupted my girlfriend and asked her to find out the homegroup password for me, but Alice is telling her that Bob knows the password.  So I checked on Bob and he was saying that "someone else" knew the password, but it wasn't him.  So I plugged a LAN cable into Bob and asked him again - this time, he's saying it's definitely Alice who knows the password.

The problem is, if Alice says Bob knows the password and Bob says Alice knows it then how am I going to tell Charlie the password?  For various (hopefully obvious) reasons I've never printed out or written down the homegroup password, so I don't know it myself and would really like one of my PCs to take responsibility for this debacle so I can straighten it all out.

Comment: Remove everything from the homegroup and start again from scratch?

Comment: From what I can find online, that seems not so straightforward, and besides the files that I supposedly have to delete don't even exist on Bob so I think it's either different in Windows 10 or something is really wrong with the homegroup.

Comment: FWIW I solved this problem using the cloud - uploaded the stuff I needed from Bob to the cloud, then downloaded them onto Charlie.  I'll be solving it in the long term using a NAS, but I'll leave this question as-is in case someone can answer it for the sake of some poor googler with the same problem.